# Unit test step debugging in Visual Studio 2012 inaccurate line stepping

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have the issue when step debugging a unit test that the execution marker is jumping inaccurately over different lines of code. I have the feeling that I had to fix this before but can't remember how to.

Does anyone have a solution to it?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure, that the file is not modified and the project was fully rebuilt before debugging the test? :) Also it probably would be helpful if you provided information about test framework you're using, which language and steps to reproduce, if possible. Otherwise it's too broad/unclear.

Comment: the jumpy behavior is present both in the unit tested and in the code being test - even after a project rebuild. c# using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

Comment: Consider adding the details to the question - they are quite important.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by hand-modifying the .testsettings file in the solution directly and removing the AgentRule section.

http://adamprescott.net/2013/01/18/vs2012-debugger-jumping-around-for-vs2010-unit-tests/